# Php: preg_split Arrays with filtered elements

Tags: php

I have this sentence:

```
17:20 - Fermata d’autobus 19:05 - La musica che non ti ho detto 21:00 - Quando l'amore brucia l'anima - Walk the Line 23:30 - Maximum Risk 01:15 - Cash Game  04:15 - Cash Game2
```

I want to split the phrase into content arrays:

```
[0]  21:00 - Quando l'amore brucia l'anima - Walk the Line 
[1]  23:30 - Maximum Risk 
[2]  01:15 - Cash Game
```

therefore with these elements only.
I tried it that way:

```
 $tt1="17:20 - Fermata d’autobus 19:05 - La musica che non ti ho detto 21:00 - Quando l'amore brucia l'anima - Walk the Line 23:30 - Maximum Risk 01:15 - Cash Game  04:15 - Cash Game2";

$arr1 = preg_split("/((2[0-3])|(0[0-3])):[0-9]*/",$tt1, -1);

foreach( array_keys($arr1) as $k ){
  $v = $arr1[$k];
  echo $v."</br>";
}
```

However, that is what I see in the print:

```
17:20 - Fermata d’autobus 19:05 - La musica che non ti ho detto 

- Quando l'amore brucia l'anima - Walk the Line 

- Maximum Risk 

- Cash Game  04:15 - Cash Game2
```

I would like the array to contain just that:

```
21:00 - Quando l'amore brucia l'anima - Walk the Line 
23:30 - Maximum Risk 
01:15 - Cash Game
```

How can I change the code for that output?

Comment: What about `17:20 - Fermata d’autobus`, `19:05 - La musica che non ti ho detto` and `04:15 - Cash Game2`? Why shouldn't they be inside the array?

Comment: I wrote what is printed to me, but I want it to be printed to me as I wrote at the end of the post.

Comment: You didn't unserstand my quiestion. What's the consistency? Why do you want these three sentences but not the others that I mentioned?

Comment: I want me to print only in the time from 20pm to 03am

Comment: That's an important thing you forgot to mention :D.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see you have already been answered, but here's a solution with only one array:

```
$re = '/(.*?)(\d{1,2}:\d{2}|$)/';

$result = [];
$matches = preg_split($re, $tt1, -1, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE | PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);

for ($i = 0; $i < count($matches) - 1; $i += 2) {
    $hour = (int) $matches[$i];

    if ($hour >= 20 || $hour <= 3)
        $result[] = $matches[$i] . $matches[$i + 1];
}

print_r($result);
```

https://3v4l.org/jG4cd

Answer (score 0):

I don't think `preg_split` is the best way to do it. I'm sure there is a complicated `preg_match` pattern which can do this. If you want to use `preg_split`, you have to split the phrase by every time (not just 20pm to 03pm), and filter out those which you want in PHP.. Like this for example:

```
$tt1="17:20 - Fermata d’autobus 19:05 - La musica che non ti ho detto 21:00 - Quando l'amore brucia l'anima - Walk the Line 23:30 - Maximum Risk 01:15 - Cash Game  04:15 - Cash Game2";

// first, split the string by the time format XX:XX, preserving the delimiters
$arr1 = array_filter(preg_split("/([0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2})/", $tt1, -1, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE));

// after that, split the result into two arrays, first one contains the times, second the phrases
$odd = $even = [];
$both = [&$even, &$odd];
array_walk($arr1, function($v, $k) use ($both) { $both[$k % 2][] = $v; });

// after that, combine the two arrays into a third one, where the keys will be the times, and values the phrases
foreach(array_combine($odd, $even) as $key => $value){
    list($hours, $minutes) = explode(':', $key);
    // explode the time so you can check the hours from 20pm to 3am
    if (intval($hours) >= 20 || intval($hours) <= 3) {
        // and output the time with the corresponding phrase
        echo $key . $value . "<br>";
    }
}
```